# Swift 2: use extensions to turn an Apple class into a singleton?

Tags: singleton, swift2

I have a lot of different classes that need to access the same GKMatch object, and I'm getting wary of how often I have to pass that GKMatch reference around. I want to find a way that any class can reliably get the same GKMatch instance.

I am proposing doing it indirectly via GKMatchDelegate, like this:

```
extension GKMatchDelegate {
    static func sharedGKMatch ()->GKMatch? { return nil }
}
```

Then, in my GKMatchDelegate subclass, I would create a `currentMatch: GKMatch?` variable and override the function to return it.

When I tried to test the concept in a playground, I did this:

```
class SingletonTest {}

extension SingletonTest {
  static func shared ()->SingletonTest? { return nil }
}

class SubclassOfSingletonTest: SingletonTest {
  static var sharedTest: SingletonTest?
  override static func shared()->SingletonTest? {
    return sharedTest
  }
}
```

And got the error message "Declarations from extensions cannot be overriden yet". From the "yet" I'm guessing they're working on it. In the meantime, is there another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Do you just want one or do you want one for every single subclass of GKMatch?

Comment: Singleton != shared object. **A singleton is a class that may not be instantiated more than once.**

Comment: Man--you guys are giving really helpful comments. With all the hullaballoo both pro-and-anti-singletons, this clarity helps. I doubt I am the only one having this question, so your answers will help a lot of people. But somebody seems to be going around giving downvotes to questions about singletons, as if asking a question with the word "singleton" in it is a bad thing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Caleb The terminology may not be 100% correct, but what Le Mot wants really is just a shared instance.

Comment: @JeremyP I agree -- was trying to explain what a singleton is so that it's clear that that's not what (s)he wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you only want one shared GKMatch, not a GKMatch for every subclass of GKMatchDelegate. In the former case, I think you are overthinking this. Just have a public var that is the singleton not in any class.

```
public var sharedGKMatch: GKMatch = GKMatch()
```

If you want to make it read only

```
public let sharedGKMatch - GKMatch()
```

It's a class so the content of GKMatch is still mutable.

Comment: You can have a public variable just sitting out there, by itself on a line, not in any class? And all the other classes can see it? If that's the case, I've been missing something *big* about Swift...

Answer (score 1):

Most applications have some sort of data model -- an object or group of objects that stores all the information that the app needs to do whatever the app does. For a word processor, for example, the data model might be a collection of open documents together with any global configuration information (printer information, fonts, preferences, etc.). For a game, the model contains the current state of the game -- board state, current locations and velocities of bad guys, number of gold coins collected, whatever.

Your app should have a data model too, and it sounds like the current `GKMatch` instance should be included in that model. That way, any class that has access to the model automatically has access to the `GKMatch`, which means that you've only got one thing that you need to pass around. That's almost certainly a better approach than adding a shared object interface to someone else's class.

Comment: Your answer and @JeremyP's answer are both very good--and totally different. I'm not sure which one to award the answer to!

Comment: @LeMotJuiced We both have plenty of rep, so I don't think it matters much -- just pick whichever you found more helpful. It's good to mark some answer as accepted eventually, though, so that the question doesn't appear unanswered. Whichever you pick, I'd encourage you to think about a data model for your app -- a single global variable or shared object isn't the end of the world, but things will get messy fast as you add more global state.

Comment: @LeMotJuiced I answered the question as posed. Caleb has given more of a "what are you really trying to do" answer. Caleb's answer is the right design, mine is the quick hack to get things out of the door.

Comment: I'm going to go with @JeremyP's answer because it also opened my eyes to a fundamental feature of Swift that I'd been overlooking. But these are both really good answers and I'd check off each of them if I could.